# Embedding HTML in an rst2pdf list-table

Tags: html, pdf, html-table, rst2pdf

I'm using [`rst2pdf`](https://code.google.com/p/rst2pdf/) 0.92 on linux, and I am trying to embed html inside a `list-table` directive, as shown in [Dimitri Christodoulou's blog](http://dimitri-christodoulou.blogspot.com/2012/01/how-to-embed-html-in-restructuredtext.html).  Robert Alsina mentioned that he had integrated this feature into [`rst2pdf`](https://code.google.com/p/rst2pdf/) 0.90.

I'm trying to build an invoice with multiple text lines per cell, the simplest way to control where the line-breaks are seems to be using a `<br>` tag.  This was my `test.rst` file:

```
Invoice for Services Rendered
=============================

.. list-table::
   :widths: 50 50
   :header-rows: 0

   * - .. raw:: html

         <p>My Name Here<br>My address here<br>City, State, Zip<br>Ph: 214-555-1212<br></p>

     - **INVOICE**
   * - This is a test
     - .. raw:: html

         <p>Invoice #20120622001<br>Date: 25 June 2012<br></p>
```

This compiles into a pdf with no problems using `rst2pdf -o test.pdf test.rst`; however, I see no text where the embedded HTML should be:

[image: rst2pdf with embedded html: broken]

I am using:

- Python 2.6.6 in a virtual-env
- docutils 0.9.1
- rst2pdf 0.92
- xhtml2pdf 0.0.4
- Debian Squeeze (Debian Linux 6.0)

How can I get rst2pdf to embed the HTML shown above in a `list-table` directive?

**EDIT**

This has been filed as [rst2pdf issue 455](https://code.google.com/p/rst2pdf/issues/detail?id=455)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed it! Sorry it took so long. Latest pisa/xhtml2pdf has completely different imports :-P

Comment: `xhtml2pdf` is installed and I can import it inside the virtual_env.  I am editing my question to include the version... although if that was missing, shouldn't rst2pdf bark with an error?

Comment: Yes, it should log "You need xhtml2pdf installed to use the raw HTML directive."

Comment: Something strange is happening, but the good news is, it's happening to me too, the imports are failing siltently. Could you file a bug for this?

Comment: Any thoughts about the feasibility of a fix?

Comment: Fixed it! Sorry it took so long. Latest pisa/xhtml2pdf has completely different imports :-P